# How to get params with backbone router?

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-routing

I'm actually getting the params like that:

```
http://localhost:9080/app?{%22address%22:%22rsPENV8NaobtaFqHmArDVVhDRRGVjmD5ep%22}
```

with this route

```
routes: {
    "app":"app"
}
```

As you can see it's really ugly and I would like to have this simple:

```
http://localhost:9080/app/rsPENV8NaobtaFqHmArDVVhDRRGVjmD5ep
```

Or something like that

```
http://localhost:9080/app/#/rsPENV8NaobtaFqHmArDVVhDRRGVjmD5ep
```

You see the idea...

But when I try app/*address or app/:address it's not working , meaning I can't catch my params or even the page.

So basically /app is server, how to get the param without the ugly way I use ?

Edit: Here is a pretty good example I found in a tutorial:

```
routes: {

    "posts/:id": "getPost",
    // <a href="http://example.com/#/posts/121">Example</a>

    "download/*path": "downloadFile",
    // <a href="http://example.com/#/download/user/images/hey.gif">Download</a>

    ":route/:action": "loadView",
    // <a href="http://example.com/#/dashboard/graph">Load Route/Action View</a>

},
```

So here the question would be how to get something like that

```
http://example.com/app/#/myparam
```

Answer (score 0):

The good rule is to separate your routes. In your situation I'd do something like this:

```
routes: {
    "p/:param_name": "getSomething"
};

...
getSomething: function(param_name) {
  ...
}
```

But if really don't need to use specific area in the router you should add your target route to the end of your routes.

```
routes: {
    "p/:param_name": "getSomething",
    ...
    ":param": "getSomething"
};
```